# Type casting craziness

Tags: smart-contracts

I am trying to execute this line `sp.amount == sp.utils.nat_to_mutez(x) * self.data.y` where `x` is the parameter of an entry point function. These are the following types:

`sp.amount: sp.TMutez`,

`x: sp.TNat`

`y: sp.TMutez`.

Even using the `sp.utils.nat_to_mutez(x)`, I still get the following error:

`Error: Type Error (sp.mul(params, sp.mutez(1)) : sp.TMutez), (self.data.y : sp.TMutez) cannot be multiplied (sp.mul(params, sp.mutez(1)) * self.data.y : sp.TMutez) (__main__, line 87)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to multiply `mutez` by `mutez` directly. [Doc](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-MUL)

> ⊢  MUL  ::  mutez  :  nat  :  A  ⇒  mutez

> ⊢  MUL  ::  nat  :  mutez  :  A  ⇒  mutez

You can do `sp.amount == sp.mul(x, self.data.y)`, which uses the overloaded multiplication (between 2 values of different types)

**Where:** `sp.amount: sp.TMutez`, `x: sp.TNat`, `y: sp.TMutez`